# csv data logs but json data doesn't?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Why would csv data log to console and json won't?
[image]

Comment: Both should work if using d3v4 or earlier for both code blocks. You can see if there is an error with `d3.json("file.json", function(error, data) {  if (error) throw error;   console.log(data); });` - one of error or data should have something.

Answer (score 0):

`d3.csv` has optional function to parse csv rows as it's being loaded [[1]](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#csv)

> An optional row conversion function may be specified to map and filter
>   row objects to a more-specific representation; see dsv.parse for
>   details. For example:

Your `console.log` is printing the csv row by row.

`d3.json` use a `JSON.parse` to convert the text into a JSON object, therefore `d3.json` doesn't offer that extra argument, as it's not parsing the JSON row by row [[2]](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json)

As `d3.json` returns a promise you can also do this pattern

```js
 d3.json("us-states.json")
   .then(data => {
     // do something with us-states.json data, now ready 

     console.log(data)

   })`
```

Comment: so the code in screenshot above (for json) should log nothing to console? really?

Comment: yes, but remember you can do `d3.json("us-states.json").then(data=> { console.log(data) })` as d3.json returns a promise. edit the answer fyi